# .NET WinForms - Programmatically End Current Edit - DataGridView

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, grid

How can you programmatically end the current cell edit without losing the change? I have my DataGridView set to EditOnEnter mode. I tried EndEdit() on the grid but this backs out the current edit.

Comment: me too @BuddyJoe, i dont know how to commitThe edit for that datagridw by programatically : for instance when the Button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is remarkably close to what I've done with the grid and without seeing any code, the only thing I did differently was to follow the call to EndEdit on the DataGridView with a call to EndEdit on the BindingSource.

Comment: You are saying this doesn't back out your current edit? And you are using EditOnEnter mode?